# Object references to memory on an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

i am finding it hard on how this code will turn out. have a look
i have `ArrayList<Object> mylist = new ArrayList<Object>();` i know this `mylist` has a pointer to `new ArrayList<Object>();` in memory, but what if i want to re-arrange items in this `mylist` and then take out the item, code looks like this

```
//supposing i have 0 to 9 items in my list,giving it a size of 10
Object o = mylist.get(2); // i retrieved the 3rd item
mylist.add(0,o); // i now place it as the first item
mylist.remove(2+1); // i want to now remove the old object. in real life the int
// is gotten somewhere else
o = mylist.get(0); // i am now retrieving the newly placed item
```

so my final question is will my `o` object be the object i got with `Object o = mylist.get(2);` ? if no, can someone guide me on how i can re-arrange my items and retrieve it again?

i was thinking i should clone `mylist` `Arraylist` and do the `get()` is that also legit?

Comment: For a test, instead of the final `o = mylist.get(0)` say `Object p = mylist.get(0)`.  Then you can check `o == p` to see if they are or are not the same object.

Comment: but wouldn't `o` be null object or the 4 item? or? because `o` was assigned to `mylist.get(2)` which i later removed it, so i think it would be shifted to another item instead? but i will try it and see @jas

Comment: Yes, o will retain its previous value. But if you are trying to 'rearrange' the items, you have to use a temp variable to store the item at index 0 so you can add it back to index 3 later.

Comment: `Object o = mylist.get(2)` makes a copy of the reference that was in the second position of `mylist` and assigns it to `o`.  Since `o` has it's own copy of the reference, nothing you do to anything in `mylist` will affect which object `o` is referring to.

Comment: @jas thanks, you made it clear even before i tested, i was a little confused thanks again, you did not place it as an answer so i could not accept it

Comment: @nick-s thanks for your support too, again you did not place it as an answer so i could not accept it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, at the end of that code the value of 'o' will be still be `myList.get(2)`.  `myList.get(2)` refers to some object in the heap, when you say `myList.add(0, o)`, you are really just adding another reference at index 0 in the array, to the same object that `myList.get()` is pointing towards. Then you removed that reference at index 2, but the pointer at index 0 is still there.

Comment: yes you are correct, thanks. i thought it works like the way object references work